# My winform lags and stucks every second

Tags: database, winforms

I've built a program that connects to an access database to receive its contents.
When I place the access database on a local folder, the program works fine (No lags).
However, if I place the database on a folder located on a global server, the programs lags and gets stuck every second.

My question would be if the program is built to check the database every few seconds automatically, or if it checks the database only when its told to.

I would really appreciate your help as I can't have any progress this way.

Thanks in advance,
Rafael.

Comment: If you don't know how the program is built, why do you suppose we know?

Answer (score 2):

No one can tell how often a client program should retrieve data from a datasource or how its triggered (polling vs notification vs user action) without knowing the requirements.

That said its sounds like you're retrieving the data very often perhaps more often then you should and you're doing it on the Main UI thread.

If I were you I'd set up some sort of caching policy and use the [BackgroundWoker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) to update my cache rather than locking up the application every few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The program will only access the database if you tell it to. Accessing a database on the network is something you should be very careful about though. If you are placing it on the network, odds are multiple people will be accessing it at the same time and you have to watch for issues that you'll run into when that happens.

If you need more than one client accessing a database, you should consider using a database like MySQL or SQL Express or some other flavor of a relational database management system.

Comment: I dont access too many times to the database. do you have another suggestion?